# Creating Fixed-KDEs in MATLAB

Tags: r, matlab, contour, kernel-density

I am creating multivariate kernel density estimations in MATLAB. I want to find 2D areas of various fixed-levels (fixed-KDEs). For example, if I choose a fixed level of 70%, then I want to calculate the 2D area that contains 70% of the points in the dataset (this would be visualized as a contour).

Here are the issues:

- I have done this in R using the same steps as in the [wikipedia section on density estimation with a full bandwidth matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_kernel_density_estimation#Density_estimation_with_a_full_bandwidth_matrix). In that example, each colored contour is a different fixed-KDE. For example, the red contour is 25%-KDE, meaning it is the smallest area that contains 25% of the data.
- Now I am doing the same steps in MATLAB using the [wikipedia section on density estimation with a diagonal bandwidth matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_kernel_density_estimation#Density_estimation_with_a_diagonal_bandwidth_matrix).

**What would be the necessary steps to produce the identical fixed-contours in MATLAB?**

---

**I have used:**

```matlab
C = contour(X,Y,density,10)
```

Where `density` is the density computed over the meshgrid `X` and `Y` (256 x 256 in my case). I did this in the hopes that it would create 10 contour lines that would each correspond to 10% intervals of fixed-KDE. In other words, contour level 5 would be the 50%-KDE, or the smallest area that contains 50% of the data.

**Problem:**

Graphically, the contours are past the points. This is the plot from the above code:

[image: output with 10 contours]

Now if I increase the number of contours:

```matlab
C = contour(X,Y,density,15)
```

I get the following plot:

[image: output with 15 contours]

I am not sure what these contours actually are in terms of the fixed-KDEs as I am talking about. Also, I am not sure why they are going so far past the points.

Again, I understand how to use the contour function to get the values of the contours and find the areas of them. That is not the problem.

I would like to know how to properly find each 10% fixed-KDE as 2D contour representations, as I have done in R and other platforms.